# Updating 1 Table with data from another table without join and using multiple criteria

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

wondering if anyone can help with this little dilemma. I have 2 relevant tables.
Switch Lighting Inventory (Table 1)
ProductPics (Table 2)
Table 1 has 20K entries with the main column being "Part Number" (SL111LG-20-30-A-B-D09)'sample part number
Table 2 has a list of 333 Items with Part Number short descriptions "Part Number" (SL111LG-B.jpg)' sample part Number.

I need to update table 1 with a new column called "Short Code" with the short code from Table 2 where the code matches table 2 up to the first hyphen as well as needing to match the B in the short code to the B in the Table 1 Part number

To offer some clarity
Every entry in table 1 that has the part number from Table 2 needs to have table 2 part number added to the short code column.
EG.

```
Table 1 SL111LG-20-30-A-B-D09  
Table 1 SL111LG-40-50-A-B-D11  
Table 1 SL111LG-20-30-A-B-D12  
Table 1 SL111LG-110-40-A-B-D13
```

These entries all need to have the short code added as SL111G-B.jpg
As there are 333 short codes to be added to 20000 entries I would dearly like to find an update query based on the multiple criteria to speed this up a bit.
There is no join between these tables.

I am okay with VBA but certainly not an experienced operator. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have tried a few update queries with multiple variables but lack the experience to do this to multiple entries in the tables without having to spend many days updating each query manually.

Comment: _"There is no join between these tables."_ - Why do you say that, when you can `JOIN` on the partial part-number columns?

Comment: Please post your actual `CREATE TABLE` statements instead of verbally describing your tables: your post is unclear about exactly which columns your `ProductPics` table has - and please explain why `ProductPics.PartNumber` contains file-names...

Comment: Based on info provided, could simply extract short code from full code with string manipulation functions.

Comment: You show sample short code **SL111G-B.jpg**. Is this short code missing "L" from "LG"?

Comment: [How to ask a good SQL question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/3820271). Sample data (in tabular form!) and expected result is much more useful than a textual description.